# Janrain ERROR : The URL you entered does not appear to be an OpenID

Tags: single-sign-on, janrain

I am using the janrain for my social login page. In that all other providers are working fine. when I use Google , it gives me this error

> The URL you entered does not appear to be an OpenID

Then I googled it, but I cannot find the solutions for this, In janrain site they are simple listed this error, but no clue for the solution.

http://developers.janrain.com/reference/javascript-api/social-login-js-api/javascript-error-codes/

and one UnAnswered question in their support portal.

https://support.janrain.com/hc/communities/public/questions/205241998-The-URL-you-entered-does-not-appear-to-be-an-OpenID-

can anyone suggest me, how to fix this?

Comment: How long have you been using Janrain?  Google deprecated OpenID support last year.  Please look at this support knowledge base post:  https://support.janrain.com/hc/en-us/articles/204377953-Migration-from-Google-to-Google-Please-update-your-application

Comment: Now Got it, I am working on old. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this, I just change the provide "google" to "googleplus". It started working.

Thankyou.